# how to get all the tags of a repository in directories

Tags: git

For example, if I have a repository with tags

```
0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 1, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 2.1, 2.2, 2.3, 2.4, 2.5, 2.6, 3.0beta
```

I'd like to make folders like

```
0.0/[repo at 0.0]
0.1/[repo at 0.1]
```

etc.

The repository is at a url, like `example.com:myrepo.git`.

Comment: Do you want the directories to contain the full repo (i.e. with the .git directory, including history), or just a work tree (a checked-out copy of the files)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `git tag` to get list of tags

Use something like below to iterate over the tagnames and create the directories:

```
GIT_WORK_TREE="../0.0" git checkout 0.0 -f
```

Answer (score 1):

Write a bash script that reads out the tags (git tag -l). then for each do clone, cd into cloned directory and checkout tag.

If you dont want a full repo in there you may try this command:

```
git archive master | tar -x -C /path/to/current/tag/
```

Comment: This will give me a full repo in each...I feel like doing this then `rm -rf .git` is sort of inefficient? But maybe not, if that's the best way of doing it.

Comment: @yodaiken: I updated my answer to only get the files without cloning the repo.